# Ubuntu networking: where these routes come from?

Tags: routing, ubuntu-20.04, networkmanager

I have a WiFi connection (`NG5` on `wlp2s0`) for main Internet surfing and a VPN (`Ufficio` on `ppp0`) to "talk" to office network. That's it.

A custom GIT server of mine allows connection only from office public IP, so I setup routing so that talking to that server happens through VPN. Pretty straightforward.

I configured that direct VPN route using GNOME settings GUI (suppose remote VPN gateway `192.168.157.100`)
[image: GNOME settings GUI]

and `route` confirms that (`GIT` is an alias in `/etc/hosts` for that target IP)

[image: entry appears in route output]

OK. But it doesn't work, because when VPN connection goes up, in routing appears few wild "GIT" entries that points to local gateway with metric 0, taking precedence over my direct route. Connection to GIT server keeps happening through my home router, that is wrong.

I mean, this is `route` before upping VPN

[image: route before VPN up]

and this is right after `nmcli c u Ufficio` (those yellow-marked are the spawned entries)

[image: spawned entries after VPN up - edited]

**THE QUESTION**

Where does those entries come from (except for `GIT/ppp0` route)? I grepped for those and they are not in VPN routing, nor in wifi one, and not in NetworkManager configs or `etc` files either. I'm stuck.
Any further explanation about the subject is welcome, as it's still pretty obscure to me. TIA.

**UPDATE**

Following suggestion from comments I ran `ip route` instead (as `route` is outdated) and the following are the routes to that GIT server. Last one is mine, but where the other two may come from?
(By the way that `192.168.1.90` is my local IP)

[image: output of ip route]

Comment: Don't use ancient `ifconfig`, `route`, `netstat` and so on in Linux. They are deprecated for more than 20 years! It is worth also mentioning that even conservative Debian omits them (the whole `net-tools` package) from the default install for around 5 years already. Use `ip` from `iproute2`. For instance, I always wondered why `route`'s output is so messed up (flags?) in comparison with `ip route`, which is clean and sane. It may also show additional information which will hint you at the reason why those routes appeared at all (e.g. show their kernel proto, or alias, or something like this).

Comment: Thank you for the hint @NikitaKipriyanov I updated the answer with the output from `ip route`.

Comment: In principle, you don't need to specify the peer IP address in the route when using peer to peer link like ppp. I mean, simple `ip route add x.x.x.x dev ppp0` is enough after VPN setting up (and it will be removed automatically during teardown). For the rest, I think NetworkManager just plays smart. If the remote GW happens *not* 192.168.157.100, the whole route as defined will be invalid. So it seems to be trying to correct this and substitutes it with "correct" gateway as it thinks. // Try to write literal "ppp0" in the gateway field, instead of IP address and see if it works.

Comment: It turned out that the GIT address is the very same of VPN gateway. This is the reason for those entries! 
But now I don't know how to route traffic to that IP that is the same for both without ambiguity! Is it possible anyway?

Comment: I think that'll need another, much simpler, question. This has found its answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case simply turns out that the GIT server and the VPN server share the same public IP. So this is where those entries are coming from. I overlooked that, sorry. IP where hiding behind their hostnames and it wasn't straight to spot.

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.