# Is it possible to connect to VPN server using VPN?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, ubuntu-20.04, networkmanager

I work from home. I connect to office network through VPN. I also have a GIT server that, by certificate, allows to connect only from office public IP, that is via VPN for me. And they are both the very same machine.

Now, I use the same public IP for connecting VPN and contacting GIT server. I have two connections: `wifi` and `vpn`, is there a way to route through `vpn` to connect to GIT server although the destination IP is ambiguous?

**UPDATE:**

From comments I received the request for a schema, so here goes a picture of how the networks work (fictious IP addresses).

[image: network schema]

As you can see I refer to the same public IP `60.70.80.90` both for establishing VPN and connecting to GIT server:

- VPN has his point of touch with outer world through the public IP;
- GIT server restricts access from public IP (ie. I cannot connect to `192.168.157.50` once VPN is established, I'd be rejected).

No problem when I go to the office, cause I naturally "quit" via `192.168.157.100`; problem is when using VPN, because I should instruct the route to `60.70.80.90` to go via VPN but that messes up with metrics and it won't work (further info on [the thread this question spinned-off from](https://superuser.com/questions/1728871/ubuntu-networking-where-these-routes-come-from)).

I mean: if VPN server and GIT server had different public IP (say GIT was: `60.70.80.91`) it'd been as easy as:

`sudo ip route add 60.70.80.91 via 192.168.157.100 dev ppp0 proto static`

But with same IP gets messy instead. So my question in the end is if it's possible to instruct that VPN route to NetworkManager, or if it's sort of a pinch.

If you need something more let me know.

Comment: In principle, nothing stops you from doing a VPN-inside-VPN, except restrictions by the VPN server. Have you tried it?

Comment: @harrymc Excuse me, I don't grasp what you mean. How would VPN-inside-VPN help with this? Just for context purposes, this question [is a spin-off of this other one](https://superuser.com/questions/1728871/ubuntu-networking-where-these-routes-come-from).

Comment: VPN-inside-VPN means connecting to one VPN and through it connecting to the other one. It's not always possible, and works better if the first VPN is entered via the router.

Comment: Your question is confusing - you might want to draw a map, including IP addresses of various systems, and also mention the VPN protocol.  I would have throught that if the GIT server connects via VPN and your client connects via VPN to the same VPN server, if not set up incompetently they would be able to directly see each other.

Comment: Not sure its relevant to you, but I've set up OpenVPN infrastructure where clients could connect to a branch office, and could speak to each other over VPN, but also to head office and VPN clients in head office.      With respect to your Subject question, you can connect to a VPN server over a VPN as well (ie VPN inside VPN), but beware of MTU (fragmentation) gotchas.

Comment: I see you are using a PPP connection for your VPN.  Don't do that, PPP has been very broken for many, many years (ie don't trust its encryption)

Comment: @davidgo following your suggestion I improved the question.

Comment: Ignoring possible very fragile and tricky policy based routing, based on your update you can't do what you are attempting as you can't both and not use 60.70.80.90 as a v vpn gatewat at the same time.  **The solution is to fix the git access controls to allow access across the vpn IP.**  Another (yuk) possibility might be to modify 60.70.80.90 to nat connections to git from the vpn interface and rewrite the source address to 60.70.80.90.

Comment: As a disclaimer I can say that I'm not the network administrator. That said, thank you @davidgo I'll give a try to your hints next week.